# Xamarin Android: WriteCharacteristic sometimes overwrites OnCharacteristicChanged

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a keep alive message coming ever 3-5 secs. When I execute WriteCharacteristic right as data is coming into OnCharacteristicChanged, it'll overwrite the OnCharacteristicChanged data received with the bytes I'm trying to send over. Is there a new API or SDK that is available that's more thread safe?

Currently using Xamarin.Android SDK 11.4.0.5

Thanks!

Tried adding a lock during write and with OnCharacteriscChanged to make sure OnCharacteriscChanged completes processing before write, but issue still exists. Was not expecting OnCharacteriscChanged and WriteCharacteristic to share the same buffer.

Comment: What is the `OnCharacteristicChanged`? Could you provide more details for this?

Comment: OnCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) this is when data is sent back to application. Results from the BluetoothGatt.WriteCharacteristic